# Error while running UDPEcho app on simulator

Tags: iphone

I am very new to iphone world and just downloaded the app and was trying to understand the application flow. For that I made same changes in the build settings but some internal error is thrown.
Through terminal it is working fine.

What changes will allow me to run that app on simulator. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am able to run the application on the simulator and they are able to receive and send signal.